# SQL - Using the With Rollup data in a calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have query results shown below. The last row is the result from With Rollup.

```
Product    Total
5300          1
5600         13
5400         66
5700        200
NULL        280
```

Is there a way to use the Rollup data (280) in a calculation to find the percentage of the total?  So I get this:

```
Product    Total     %
5300          1     3%
5600         13     5%
5400         66    22%
5700        200    72%
NULL        280
```

Comment: shouldnt product 1 be '0.3%' (1/280)

Comment: Yes it should be.  I just slapped a 1% in there as an example.  I did an edit.

Comment: possibly using a window function or using a cte`With CTE as (yourQUERY) Select Product, Total, total/(Select total from cte where product is null)*100 from cte`  thinking about window now...

Comment: yes, in an outer query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931118/calculate-running-percentage-in-sql

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy with a CTE. Now depend on how strict are on your output.

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/50999/3)

```
WITH total as (
     SELECT Total
     FROM sumarize
     WHERE Product IS NULL
 )
 SELECT S.*, (S.Total * 1.0 / t.Total)*100 as porcent
 FROM sumarize S, total t
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a windowing function like this

```
SELECT (Total/(SUM(Total) OVER(PARTITION BY Product)))*100 AS Percent
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the right way. First i couldnt copy the line on my fiddle to try it. And the denominator should be always the same, so not sure if calculate the `SUM() over partition` will give you that.

Comment: ok, so you don't want to partition it?  then just use `SUM(total) OVER ()`